Newly added items cannot move in gridstack.js?
MainPage.razor
<button @onclick="@AddItem">Add</button>

<GridStackComponent GridStackId="grid-stack-1" PlaceholderItems="@placeholdersbefore" />

@code {
    public record Placeholder(string Id, string Name, int x, int y, int w, int h);
    
    List<Placeholder> placeholdersbefore = new() {
        new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "TEST1", 0, 0, 12, 2),
        new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "TEST2", 0, 2, 12, 2)};

    protected async void AddItem()
    {
        placeholdersbefore.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "TEST3", 0, 4, 6, 2));
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

GridStackComponent.razor
@using System.Text.Json

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">

    <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px dotted gray;">

        <div class="grid-stack">
            @foreach (var p in PlaceholderItems)
            {
                <div class="grid-stack-item" gs-id="@p.Id" gs-x="@p.x" gs-y="@p.y" gs-w="@p.w" gs-h="2" >
                    <div class="grid-stack-item-content">@p.Name</div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

@code {

    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string GridStackId { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public List<Placeholder> PlaceholderItems { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("DotNetReference.init", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("InitiateGridStack");
    }


    [JSInvokable("OnWidgetChanged")]
    public void OnWidgetChanged(string changeSet)
    {
    }
}

JS code
window.InitiateGridStack = function () {
    window.grids = GridStack.initAll({
        margin: 1
    });
}

I'm using Gridstack.js with Blazor server application. I want to add/remove items dynamically from the gridstack.
When I click Add button, it adds the new widget to the list and re-renders the gridstack. But the newly added item cannot move. Its locked. How can I fix this issue?
